# How would I Select two columns from a Table, then use the results to Select another Table, then join them together

Tags: postgresql

So I want to get task_ids and order_ids from a POOL table, where user_id=x
then I want to use that order_id to get a few columns from an ORDER table, and join them together

like this (not correct but might convey better):

SELECT task_id, **order_id** FROM pool WHERE user_id= $1 AND  (status = 0 OR status = 1),
[user.id]

*then*

SELECT cost, date, FROM order WHERE order_id=(all **order_ids** from the previous SELECT I did)

then join them together, as the resulting rows:

| task_id | order_id | cost | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

is this possible? or would it be easier to two 2 separate queries?

Comment: Assuming no relations between `pool` and `order` look at [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Comment: You could use CTE like user above suggested or use subquery Select * from (your query above).

Comment: I think there is a relation between pool and order. They both have the order_id.  Sorry I'm not sure, I'm new to sql.

Comment: Also could you write out what the code would be? I think I get subquery , so I could get the rows from pool table, then use the order_id column from that result to get all the rows from the order table. but how do I then join both those rows together?

Comment: `select p.task_id, p.order_id, o.date, o.cost from pool as p join orders as o on p.order_id = o.order_id where p.user_id = $1 and(p.status = 0 OR p.status = 1);`?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), I was able to put this together, and it does work!
But I don't know if it is efficient, and using a subquery instead probably would be better, since this is creating a temp table that is used only one. If so, how would you convert this to using subquery?

```sql
WITH p AS (
    SELECT task_id, order_id
    FROM pool
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND (status = 0 OR status = 1)
)
SELECT  p.order_id, date, cost, task_id
FROM orders
INNER JOIN p ON orders.order_id=p.order_id
```